# Send one Model from ViewModel back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using a ViewModel to pass various models to the view. Now in a form, I would like to return one model (ResetTypeSingleModel) out of this ViewModel but the controller’s method can only expect the ViewModel:
My ViewModel:

```
public class ResetViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<ResetTypeModel> TableResetType {get; set;}

    public ResetTypeSingleModel SingleResetType {get; set;}

    }
```

My controller (of course I changed it to ResetTypeSingleModel):

```
public IActionResult ResetDevice([FromForm] ResetViewModel rtm){ }
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetDevice", "Sccm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_reset" }))
{  
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SingleResetType.resettype_id, new SelectList(Model.TableResetType, "resettype_id" , "resettype_name"), "Please select",  new { @CssClass="ddl_resettype", @id="ddl_resettype", @class = "form-control" })

   <input type="submit" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" />

}
```

How can I accomplish that I submit to the controller only this model and not the complete viewModel?

Thanks
Stephan

---

Update:
So I tried to change the names of the fields but then the pattern etc. does not work anymore:

```
@{ string name = @Html.NameFor(model => Model.SingleResetType.hostname).ToString().Split(".").Reverse().ToList()[0];}       
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SingleResetType.hostname)
        @Html.TextBox(name, null, new { @class = "form-control", @id=name, name =name, })
```

So I guess the only way is to use javascript

Comment: Before we can suggest a solution to your question, what do you want to accomplish by sending a complete model in your view model?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand the question correct. I pass a model to the view with information from the database, want the user to select a value in the view, add some information and send it back to the controller.

Comment: ok, I think the error is the name attribute which should not contain the full model name

Comment: If I understand the question correct,i'm afraid you should use like `<button onclick=""></button>`